# validation set get higher accuracy than training set for LSTM RNN as learning rate gets smaller

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently trying to test the differences of behavior between a LSTM RNN and a GRU RNN on the prediction of time series ( classification 1/0 if time series goes up or down). I use the fit_generator method (as in Keras François Chollet book's)

I feed 30 point to the network and the next point has to be classified as up or down. The training set samples are reshuffled while the validation samples are not of course.

If I do not change the default value of the Learning rate ( 10-3 for adam algorithm) then the usual happens, the training set tends to be overfitted after a certain number of epochs, both for LSTM and GRU cells.

[LSTM 1 layer 128N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jim9f.png)

Note that my plots are averaged with 10 simulations ( this way I get rid of the particular weight random initialization )

If I choose lower learning rates, the training and validation accuracy see below the impact of a different learning rate, it appears to me like the training set is not able to overfit anymore (???)

[learning rate impact on GRU network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTFAS.png)

When I compare the LSTM and the GRU, it's even worse, the validation set gets higher accuracy than the training set in the LSTM case. For the GRU case, the curve are close, but the training set is still higher

[2 layer LSTM LR=1e-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqlQR.png)

[2 layer GRU LR=1e-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSarc.png)

Note that this is less emphasized for 1 layer LSTM

[1 layer LSTM LR=1e-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsHth.png)

I have tested this with 1 or 2 layers and for a different validation set but results are similar.

extract of my code below:

```
modelLSTM_2a = Sequential()
modelLSTM_2a.add(LSTM(units=32, input_shape=(None, data.shape[-1]),return_sequences=True))
modelLSTM_2a.add(LSTM(units=32, input_shape=(None, data.shape[-1]),return_sequences=False))
modelLSTM_2a.add(Dense(2))
modelLSTM_2a.add(Activation('softmax'))
adam  = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
modelLSTM_2a.compile(optimizer= adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Would someone have a clue of what may happening?

I'm really puzzled by this behavior, especially by the impact of the learning rate in the LSTM case